# Simplest way of defining autocomplete subcommands

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I have a CLI program that has a few nested subcommands, like

```
program task
program task start
program task stop
program config
program config set
program config unset
```

And I'd like to implement a very rudimentary bash autocomplete for it. I don't necessarily want to go the route of defining a [shell-function](https://devmanual.gentoo.org/tasks-reference/completion/index.html) for it, but was hoping to simply use wordlists, like

```
complete -W "task config" -- "program"
```

But it doesn't seem I can define nested completion wordlists that way, like

```
complete -W "start stop" -- "program task"
complete -W "set unset" -- "program config"
```

Is there a simple way of achieving autocompletion for such commands?

Comment: quick comment, not an answer, but have a look at _get_comp_words_by_ref, which is a function in the bash_completion script. This is sourced in your .bashrc, so should be available for you to use.  (on my distro it's at `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`)

Comment: Hm, can you explain on how to use it? I've tried reading its docs and seeing some uses but I don't understand what it's for...

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of the _get_comp_words_by_ref function I mentioned in my comments.

```
# "program" completion

# This file should either be copied in your system-defined place where other
# such completion scripts reside, such as /usr/share/bash-completion/completions
# or /etc/bash_completion.d (check which one is called by your .bashrc file).
#
# Alternatively, simply 'source' it in your .bashrc file.


function _program () {

  _get_comp_words_by_ref -c CURRENT_WORD -p PREVIOUS_WORD -w WORDS_ARRAY -i CURRENT_WORD_INDEX


  if   test "$CURRENT_WORD_INDEX" -eq 2     &&   # dealing with a second-level subcommand
       test "${WORDS_ARRAY[0]}" = "program"
  then if   test "$PREVIOUS_WORD" = "task"
       then COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "start stop" -- $CURRENT_WORD ) )
       elif test "$PREVIOUS_WORD" = "config"
       then COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "set unset" -- $CURRENT_WORD ) )
       fi
  elif test "$CURRENT_WORD_INDEX" -eq 1 && test "$PREVIOUS_WORD" = "program"
  then COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "task config" -- $CURRENT_WORD ) )
  fi

}

complete -F _program program
```

Source this file and try typing program co[TAB], program config u[TAB], etc.